# Is this a valid usage of structure assignment in C?

Tags: c, memory-management, matlab

Q: Please comment on the usage of structures and structure assignment operations in C

I am working on converting a MATLAB program to C using BLAS and LAPACK for linear algebra support. The MATLAB code uses cell arrays. I created a Matrix datatype and a Cell data-type.

A section of the header file/implementation:

```
#define ASSERT(c,m) 
#define PREC double

#define ZEROS(r,c) (zeros(r,c))
#define ONES(r,c) (ones(r,c))
#define EYE(r,c) (eye(r,c))
#define ALLOCM(r,c) (alloc_matrix(r,c))
#define PRINTM(M) (print_matrix(M))
#define FREEM(M) (free_matrix(M))

#define ALLOCC(r,c) (alloc_cell(r,c))
#define GETMC(C,r,c) (get_matrix_from_cell(C,r,c))
#define SETMC(C,r,c,M) (set_matrix_in_cell(C,r,c,M))
#define FREEC(C) (free_cell(C))

/* Matrix */
typedef struct {
  PREC * array;
  int rows; // The number of rows in the matrix
  int cols; // The number of columns in the matrix
}Matrix;


/* Cell of Matrices */
typedef struct {
  Matrix * array; // Cell array of matrices stored in row major form
  int rows;  // Number of rows in Cell array
  int cols;  // Number of cols in Cell array
}Cell;


/* Matrix utility functions */
Matrix  alloc_matrix(int rows, int cols);
Matrix  zeros(int rows, int cols);
Matrix  ones(int rows, int cols);
Matrix  eye(int rows, int cols);
Matrix  corrcov(Matrix matrix);
void print_matrix(Matrix matrix);
void free_matrix(Matrix  matrix);

/* Cell array utility functions */
Cell alloc_cell(int rows, int cols);
INLINE Matrix get_matrix_from_cell(Cell cell, int row, int col);
INLINE void set_matrix_in_cell(Cell  cell, int row, int col, Matrix matrix);
void free_cell(Cell cell); 

// Implementation
Matrix 
alloc_matrix(int rows, int cols){

  Matrix matrix;

  ASSERT(rows > 0 && cols > 0, FATAL_NEGATIVE_DIMENSIONS);

  matrix.array = (PREC *) malloc(sizeof(PREC) * rows * cols);

  ASSERT(matrix.array != NULL, FATAL_NO_MEMORY);

  matrix.rows = rows;

  matrix.cols = cols;

  return matrix;
}



Matrix 
zeros(int rows, int cols){

  int i;

  int size;

  Matrix matrix;

  matrix = alloc_matrix(rows, cols);

  for(i = 0, size = rows * cols; i < size ; i++){
    matrix.array[i] = 0.0;
  } 

  return matrix;
}



void
print_matrix(Matrix matrix){

  int i;  

  int j;

  int k;

  int rows = matrix.rows;

  int cols = matrix.cols;

  ASSERT(rows > 0 && cols > 0, FATAL_NEGATIVE_DIMENSIONS);  

  ASSERT(matrix.array != NULL, FATAL_NULL_POINTER);

  printf("\n Rows: %d, Cols: %d\n", rows, cols);

  for(i = 0 ; i < rows; i++){
    for(j = 0, k = i * cols; j < cols; j++){
      printf("%8.6f  ", matrix.array[ k + j ]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }  

}


void 
free_matrix(Matrix matrix){

  ASSERT(matrix.array != NULL, FATAL_NULL_POINTER);

  free(matrix.array);

  matrix.array = NULL; 

}


Cell 
alloc_cell(int rows, int cols){

  Cell cell;

  ASSERT(rows > 0 && cols > 0, FATAL_NEGATIVE_DIMENSIONS);

  cell.array = (Matrix *) malloc(sizeof(Matrix) * rows * cols);

  ASSERT(cell.array != NULL, FATAL_NO_MEMORY);

  cell.rows = rows;

  cell.cols = cols;

  return cell; 
}



void 
free_cell(Cell cell){

  int i;

  int size;

  int rows = cell.rows;

  int cols = cell.cols;

  ASSERT(rows > 0 && cols > 0, FATAL_NEGATIVE_DIMENSIONS);

  ASSERT(cell.array != NULL, FATAL_NULL_POINTER);

  for( i = 0, size = rows * cols; i < size; i++){
    free_matrix(cell.array[i]);                       
  }

  free(cell.array);

}


INLINE Matrix 
get_matrix_from_cell(Cell cell, int row, int col){

  Matrix matrix;

  int rows = cell.rows;

  int cols = cell.cols;

  ASSERT(cell.array != NULL, FATAL_NULL_POINTER);

  ASSERT(rows > 0 && cols > 0, FATAL_NEGATIVE_DIMENSIONS);

  ASSERT(row >= 0 && row < rows, FATAL_INDEX_OUT_OF_BOUNDS);

  ASSERT(col >= 0 && col < cols, FATAL_INDEX_OUT_OF_BOUNDS);

  matrix = cell.array[(row * cols) + col];

  return matrix; 
}



INLINE void
set_matrix_in_cell(Cell cell, int row, int col, Matrix matrix){

  int rows = cell.rows;

  int cols = cell.cols;

  ASSERT(cell.array != NULL, FATAL_NULL_POINTER);

  ASSERT(rows > 0 && cols > 0, FATAL_NEGATIVE_DIMENSIONS);

  ASSERT(row >= 0 && row < rows, FATAL_INDEX_OUT_OF_BOUNDS);

  ASSERT(col >= 0 && col < cols, FATAL_INDEX_OUT_OF_BOUNDS);

  cell.array[(row * cols) + col] = matrix;

}
```

Notice that I do not return pointers from functions that allocate Matrix type objects or Cell type objects. I return a plain Matrix or Cell object, but I allocate the arrays (PREC  type for matrices and Matrix type for cells - where PREC is double or float) inside these functions.

This is convenient because:

1. struct assignment is a valid operation in C (I know that the
   dynamically allocated data is not duplicated, only a reference to
   it)
2. to get to an element inside a Matrix, I can use the `dot` syntax
   instead of `->` syntax (also I believe I may have to de-reference
   just once if I use the dot syntax - matrix.array[i] vs matrix->array[i]
   (I mean the matrix in matrix->array[i] is a pointer to a Matrix object, 
    as I am comparing items on a stack vs those that are dynamically 
    allocated)
3. Most of the Matrix objects and Cell objects ( barring the
   dynamically allocated memory ) are on the stack and are
   automatically freed when function exits and I feel, its easier to
   keep track of objects that are no longer in use and free them when
   necessary.

I profiled a sample program (that uses this interface) with Valgrind.

The sample program:

```
#include "matutil.h"

int main(){

  Matrix mz;

  Cell cell;

  mz = ZEROS(3,3);

  PRINTM(mz);

  cell = ALLOCC(1,1);

  SETMC(cell,0,0,mz);  

  PRINTM(GETMC(cell, 0 , 0));

  FREEC(cell);

  return 0;
}
```

The problem is matrix object (Matrix mz) that I start with does not have its array field explicitly initialized and so, Valgrind reports

```
==17433== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
```

Is this an issue? Are there any pitfalls that I should be aware of before I proceed with this design?

Thank you.

Comment: Okay. This is sorted now. The valgrind profile is hosted here: I get the Conditional Jump ... error when I do a plain alloc (not zeroing out the array) and no errors when the array is zeroes out. That probably explains why you don't get an error, because in the sample program I have given, it uses the zeros function to allocate memory, but I have been running my code with just alloc_matrix that just allocates memory but does not initialize it.

http://filebox.vt.edu/users/maheshnm/MVN_RAND/valgrind-op-plainalloc

http://filebox.vt.edu/users/maheshnm/MVN_RAND/valgrind-op-zeroalloc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### About your valgrind issue

I don't think the valgrind warning is about uninitialized fields in Matrix. Your `zeros` functions does the initialization, right? I tested myself with this code:

```
Matrix zeros(int rows, int cols) {
    Matrix tmp;
    int i;

    tmp.rows = rows;
    tmp.cols = cols;
    tmp.array = malloc(sizeof(float) * rows * cols);

    for(i = 0; i < rows * cols; i++)
        tmp.array[i] = 0;

    return tmp;
}
```

I have no valgrind warnings. Sharing a snippet of code wich really produces the valgrind warning would help.

### Other remarks

- If you want to free the memory automatically and have your allocated memory copied, C++ will help.
- I don't understand your point about dot syntax though. You're only adding one level of nesting, this does not mean you're going to use "*" or "->" any less.
- `matrix->array[i]` is wrong since `->` and `[]` both dereference your pointer: this is not going to compile
- Why don't you use a PREC** pointer? It is probably easier to use and will avoid errors
- Are you trying to make your MATLAB code fast? Matrix operations are probably very fast using matlab. If there's another part of your code wich is slow, consider using [MEX-files](http://www.mathworks.fr/support/tech-notes/1600/1605.html#intro).

Comment: Hello, I have added the implementation to the code above. You are right about using * in place of ->. I can already see that I am using * more often. About matrix->array[i] - I wanted to compare a statically allocated matrix object and a dynamically allocated matrix object, I was not clear though. I meant to say matrix in matrix->array[i] was a pointer to a Matrix object. The easy solution is to implement Matrix ** inside a Cell object. And I am sure you must be right about MATLAB being faster. I may fall back on optimizing that code instead. :)

Comment: The code that I am working on already uses a number of MEX components. I profiled it and found that the MEX components are the ones that are using the largest chunk of CPU. I just wanted to give ATLAS/LAPACK a shot. And besides the MATLAB code does numerous branching and loop stuff. If nothing works, I may have to MEX those portions.

Comment: I still have no error (you forgot free_matrix and a few #defines like PREC or ASSERT, though). What line and file does Valgrind mention in your error?

Comment: I am sorry, PREC and ASSERT were defined in a different file. I have disabled ASSERT for now, defined PREC as double. I have added free_matrix to the code.

Comment: Okay. This is sorted now. The valgrind profile is hosted here: http://filebox.vt.edu/users/maheshnm/MVN_RAND/valgrind-op-plainalloc

http://filebox.vt.edu/users/maheshnm/MVN_RAND/valgrind-op-zeroalloc 

I get the Conditional Jump ... error when I do a plain alloc (not zeroing out the array) and no errors when the array is zeroed out. That probably explains why you don't get an error, because in the sample program I have given, it uses the zeros function to allocate memory, but I have been running my code with just alloc_matrix that just allocates memory but does not initialize it.

Comment: Makes sense. It could be any garbage value if not zeroed out. Good luck optimizing your code.

Comment: Yes, I am hoping I can get some real speedup.